# What is a good KDE equivalent to tilda on Gnome?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome, kde

Or is tilda already KDE equivalent? Performance is important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yakuake.

http://yakuake.kde.org/